# Find intersection of all plan $n^{2}x+(2n-1)y+nz=3$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Problem :
Let $(P_{n})_{n}$ the families of plan equation :

$$P_{n}~~:~~n^{2}x+(2n-1)y+nz=3$$
And note that $E$ are the intersection of all this plan e.o :

$$E=\{~M(x,y,z)~/~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}~,M\in P_{n} \}$$

Choose the right option :

$E=?$

$•~\varnothing$

$•~E~\text{is the plan}~ x+y+z=3$

$•~E~\text{is the droit}~\begin{cases}x+y+z=3,\\y=-3\end{cases}$

$•~E~\text{is the point} (0,-3,6)$

I don't know how but for $n=1$ and $n=0$ the intersection is the suggestion 3
But for all I don't know
Can you assist!

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you solve the system you get for $n\in\{1,2,3\}$:
\begin{eqnarray}x+y+z&=&3\\
4x+3y+2z&=&3\\
9x+5y+3z&=&3\\
\end{eqnarray}
which is a single point $(0,-3,6)$. Now check if it lies in every plane:
$$ n^2\cdot 0+(2n-1)\cdot (-3) +n\cdot 6 = 3$$ which is true for all $n$,
so you chose last answer.

Comment: So I spent my time for not saying even thank you?